# Is it possible to extend the Model in the Razor file into a separate Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I have a Razor cshtml file, that references a server-side MyModel and a client-side javascript file where I like to keep all my JavaScript functionality:

foo.cshtml

```
@model BunnyModel
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
}
```

foo.js

```
function doStuff() {
    $("#blah").text("Bunnies: " + @Model.BunnieCollection.Count);
}
```

Of course, VS2015 doesn't recognize my BunnyModel in the foo.js file.

Is there some type of hint I can give to Visual Studio so that it would provide Model intellisense in the .js file?

Comment: Razor code is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view and razor code is not evaluated in external js files so this is not possible

Comment: Couldn't you use TypeScript for the javascript and have an `interface` for the model? I know its a leap but that /would/ give you intellisense.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I understand that, but I need intellisense while I am coding in the .js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either put the js in the cshtml:

```
@model BunnyModel
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doStuff() {
            $("#blah").text("Bunnies: " + @Model.BunnieCollection.Count);
        }
    </script>
}
```

...or put the variable in the scope and reference it in the external function:

cshtml

```
@model BunnyModel
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var bunnieCount = @Model.BunnieCollection.Count
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
}
```

foo.js

```
function doStuff() {
    $("#blah").text("Bunnies: " + bunnieCount);
}
```

Comment: I am not a huge fan of this approach, since the bunny model could be a really complicated one.  I'd have to copy a lot of things.  I suspect that I will end up converting the Model to JSON and assigning it to a javascript variable.  Also, not great.

Comment: Yep, serializing is the way to go. I don't think anyone's really a 'fan' of this approach, just don't have any good alternatives.

Comment: I don't see why Visual Studio couldn't have a directive (similar to the one used in the razor file) that tells it to provide intellisense for a specific model.

Comment: They probably could. That isn't the problem. foo.js isn't rendered in the MVC pipeline; it's served statically in a different request. So RazorView never resolves '@Model.BunnieCollection.Count' in foo.js. Even if it was rendered in the pipeline, it's a different request, so there's be no model.